How electric and magnetic fields are created in em waves?
I am a high school student in my first chapter on electrostatic I learned that electric and magnetic field depends on magnitude of charge and varies by inverse square law.Recently I studied about em waves and I have a question about the oscillating electric and magnetic fields of em waves. Suppose in deep space I have a charge of magnitude say equal to 1.6×10^-19 Coulomb and now this charge starts accelerating so it will radiate em waves and these em waves will travel at speed of light to reach large distance. My question is that how such a small charge can create electric and magnetic field upto such large distances when accelerated and it cannot create electric and magnetic field upto that level when in uniform motion in straight line or at rest

What kind of “how” answer are you looking for? This is what solving Maxwell’s equations predicts, and what we observe. Why would the wave stop at some distance? Do you realize that it gets weaker and weaker? In what sense is 2C a small charge? It’s something like a million trillion times the charge of an electron.

Please read the question again

I want to know how such a small charge can create electric and magnetic field upto such large distances while accelerated and the same charge cannot create electric and magnetic field upto that level when in uniform motion or at rest

and the same charge cannot create electric and magnetic field upto that level when in uniform motion or at rest You said nothing about this in your question. You need to edit again.

When you solve Maxwell’s equations, the field of a charge at rest or in uniform motion drops off like $1/r^2$ but the field of an accelerated charge drops off like $1/r$. That makes a big difference at large distances.

So a small charge can create oscillating electric and magnetic field upto billions of metres

Yes, a small field. It’s not like there is some cutoff where the field goes to zero. It just gets smaller and smaller. We might not be able to measure it.

Take your time and think about your questions and the hints (comments or answers) you have already got a t a time. Don't explode into several new questions on every new thought you get. Running in all directions at once will get you nowhere.

If you ask too many questions that get downvoted, you may get a temporary suspension from being able to ask new questions.

Okay I will not ask from now

The fundamental rules to remember are as follows:
When a charge experiences an acceleration, its surrounding electric field lines (which start out straight) must curve to follow it as it begins to move.
When electric field lines get bent like this, a magnetic field is created as the bend grows.
When the bend begins to straighten out again, the magnetic field reverses itself and shrinks.
The shrinkage of the magnetic field lines generates an electric field. Rinse and repeat!
These two mechanisms make the resulting wave (with electric and magnetic components) propagate all by itself, cycling back and forth over and over again, between the electric and magnetic components- forever.
The rules governing this overall process are contained in Maxwell's Equations.
